# Help changing views HTML output

Tags: views

I have View set up to display a list of images that are related to nodes elsewhere in my site, and I've styled them so that hovering over them darkens the image and displays the node's title. Unfortunately, the title div obscures the image, and making the title into a link only affects the title text.

What I'd like to do is wrap the title div in  tags, so this:

```
<div><a href="target">Title</a></div>
```

Turns into this:

```
<a href="target"><div>Title</div></a>
```

I have an inkling that I'll have to do this either with hooks or in one of the views.php files, but I'm not sure where to start; can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter title and use token like: `<a href="target"><div>[Title]</div></a>`